# Select rows from data.frame using vector of names

Tags: r

I would like to keep just ~1200 rows from my `data.frame` but to remove rest of rows I have to use the vector of "gene names" which can be found in this `data.frame`.

My data (just couple of rows):

```
> tbl_ready2
  Gene.name X1_1 X1_2     X1_3     X1_4      X1_5      X1_6      X1_7      X1_8      X1_9  X1_10     X1_11 X1_12    X1_13     X1_14 X1_15     X1_16    X1_17
1 AT1G01050    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.7137613 0.0000000 1.1431194 0.0000 0.0000000     0 0.000000 0.0000000     0 0.0000000 0.000000
2 AT1G01080    0    0 1.912532 1.263598 0.9972625 0.8363335 0.9984333 1.0027375 0.7207666 0.0000 0.7155959     0 0.000000 0.0000000     0 0.0000000 0.000000
3 AT1G01090    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.1864505 0.0000000 0.1057995 0.7634527 0.9794 1.1207689     1 1.276209 0.9701439     0 0.8552922 0.000000
4 AT1G01220    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000 0.0000000     0 0.000000 0.0000000     0 0.0000000 0.000000
5 AT1G01320    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000 1.0000000     1 1.106175 0.8972847     0 0.6782750 1.313616
      X1_18    X1_19 X1_20    X1_21 X1_22 X1_23     X1_24
1 0.0000000 0.000000     0 0.000000     0     0 0.0000000
2 0.0000000 0.000000     0 0.000000     0     0 0.5538011
3 1.0182444 2.138711     0 1.554696     0     0 1.6815517
4 0.0000000 0.000000     0 0.000000     0     0 0.0000000
5 0.7313952 1.268605     0 2.128264     0     0 1.0000000
```

vector of names (not all of them):

```
> vec
   [1] AT1G02500 AT1G07780 AT1G08250 AT1G08630 AT1G09780 AT1G09795 AT1G10060 AT1G10070 AT1G11790 AT1G12230 AT1G13440 AT1G14810 AT1G15710 AT1G16300 AT1G17290
  [16] AT1G17745 AT1G18500 AT1G18640 AT1G22020 AT1G22170 AT1G22410 AT1G23310 AT1G24807 AT1G24909 AT1G25083 AT1G25155 AT1G25220 AT1G29410 AT1G31180 AT1G31230
  [31] AT1G31860 AT1G32380 AT1G32440 AT1G32480 AT1G33320 AT1G36370 AT1G44820 AT1G48470 AT1G48850 AT1G48860 AT1G50090 AT1G50110 AT1G54100 AT1G54340 AT1G55880
  [46] AT1G55920 AT1G56190 AT1G58080 AT1G62800 AT1G63290 AT1G65930 AT1G69370 AT1G70580 AT1G71100 AT1G71920 AT1G72330 AT1G72810 AT1G74030 AT1G74040 AT1G75330
```

so I tried this function. Thought it should work but it doesn't...

```
data <- tbl_ready[intersect(vec, tbl_ready[,1])]
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using tbl_ready and tbl_ready2 in your example. If tbl_ready2 is the data.frame you want to subset, you could try:

```
data<-tbl_ready2[tbl_ready2$Gene.name %in% vec,]
```

Comment: `tbl_ready2` was just an example. I used the correct `data.frame` but the function was not correct. Your function works pretty well. Thx!